# Ajax send data to D3JS in Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a dashboard in the Flask framework, with D3 for visualization, and AJAX.

- **Desired behaviour** -

1. user enters two numbers into a webpage (`/calc`, see routes below),
2. These two numbers will multiplied by 2 (to represent some calculations to be done on the input) in `app.py`, to be the width and height of a rectangle to be drawn by D3.
3. Calculated width and height passed back to `index.html` as the width and height of a rectangle to be rendered on screen.

- **Current behaviour** - user input is successfully read and logged to console.log as a JS object with width and height values calculated as expected, but I'm not sure how to pass these two values back to `index.html` for D3 to read and render, i.e. kind of stuck halfway through (3).

The actual use case is rather more complex (uploading data to be presented as a bunch of scatterplots and bar charts etc.), but I've reduced it to this minimal state just to isolate and solve the problem of piping data from one layer to another. I sense that this is actually a really simple answer...but can't seem to figure this one out, because I'm using AJAX this time, instead of `render_template(..., data=data)` as I'd usually do.

What I have so far is as follows:

**Directory structure**

```
/static
|__ /js
   |__ script.js
/templates
|__ index.html
app.py
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, json

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route('/calc')
def calc():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/calc_func', methods=['POST'])
def calc_func():
    """Function attached to the button click, via script.js. 
    Multiples the form numbers by 2 to represent some calculations to be done on the input.
    """
    num1 = request.form['num1']
    num2 = request.form['num2']
    width = float(num1) * 2
    height = float(num2) * 2

    return json.dumps({'status':'OK', 'width':width, 'height':height})


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

**script.js**

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var user = $('#num1').val();
        var pass = $('#num2').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/calc_func',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**index.html**

Note that at this point, I'd like the `width` and `height` values as calculated by `app.py` to be passed to the `data` variable in the `<script>` section below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Flask + AJAX + D3</title>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-signin" role="form">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Enter 2 numbers</h2>
            <input type="text" id="num1" name="num1" class="form-control" placeholder="First number" required
                autofocus>
            <input type="text" id="num2" name="num2" class="form-control" placeholder="Second number" required>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button">Add!</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="myGraph"></div>

    <script>
        var svg = d3.select("div.myGraph")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 400)
            .attr("height", 200);
            
        // "width" and "height" should be the values for keys "x2" and "y2"
        var data = [{x1: 20, x2: 60, y1: 30, y2: 50}];

        var rects = svg.selectAll("div.myGraph")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", d=> d.x1)
            .attr("y", d=> d.y1)
            .attr("width", d=> d.x2 - d.x1)
            .attr("height", d=> d.y2 - d.y1)
            .attr("fill", "teal");
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```